# Input tag doesn't get displayed in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className = "space-y-4">

    <div>

      <label  htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <div>
        <input type="text" id="username" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeName} />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

it gets displayed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39J6E.png)
So the input does get render but doesn't get shown, any ideas?

Comment: That isn't how it would normally behave. Perhaps you have some CSS causing that effect. You need to provide a [mcve]. You could try [providing a live demo with React](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support).

Comment: @Quentin that React demo link is outdated, stack snippets can't handle JSX anymore, see latest comments below the answer

Answer (score 0):

apparently that is tailwind default, to have a border you must add the border class, thank you for your answers.